# Why is the determinant test attractive for the Convex Hull algorithm?

Tags: computational-geometry, convex-hulls

Given three points $p$, $q$, and $r$, you can determine whether $r$ is to the left or right of the line $pq$ by taking the determinant of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 & p_x & p_y \\ 1 & q_x & q_y \\ 1 & r_x & r_y \end{bmatrix}$. Additionally, that determinant is twice the surface area of the triangle formed by $pqr$, by the Shoelace method.

Considering these two facts, why is this test attractive for an algorithm that determines the Convex Hull of a set, for a) integer coordinates, and b) floating point coordinates? Is it because of the complexity class of the test, or what?

Comment: Could you provide more details?  What do you mean by attractive?  Why do you say that the test is attractive?  How attractive the test may depend on what computational model you're using or what is important to your computation.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  [For some basic information about writing math](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)
at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editikng how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Rahul I mean I've corrected the typo in my template.  I just wanted to add link pointing to the list of templates on MathMeta.SE to avoid arguments.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Unfortunately I can't. "Attractive" is all I'm given. I simply need to provide an argument on any basis.

Comment: Some things to think about: (1) What are the alternatives?  (2) How stable is the calculation? (3) How many operations are needed in the calculation? (4) Can it be generalized to higher dimensions?  How attractive this computation is depends on what is important to you (speed, accuracy, large numbers of data points, etc.)

Comment: I don't understand why it would differ between integer and floating point coordinates.